# Xpath expression to find the first, the second and the third occurrence in Microsoft ADF

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, azure-data-factory

I'm able to extract the first value of `PICKUP` address using this expression and this [online tool](http://xpather.com/):

`.//Address[normalize-space(AddressTypeCode)="PICKUP"]/AddressLines/Value[1]`

I've followed [this article](https://the.agilesql.club/2021/02/adf-xml-objects-and-xpath-in-the-expression-language/) to use Xpath expression in ADF but it doesn't seem to work there:

```
string(//*[name()="AddressTypeCode"][text()="PICKUP"][name()="AddressLines"]/../*[name()="Value"][position()=1])
```

XML sample: https://pastebin.com/ghLAnRP1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: value of the first <Value></Value> tag inside PICKUP, i.e: OT Group

Comment: So only the first one? How about *...second and third*? Also did you try `.//Address[normalize-space(AddressTypeCode)="PICKUP"]/AddressLines/Value[1]/text()`? Why do you need to use `fn:string`?

Comment: As stated in the linked article: `when you do something like run an XPath selector like //ElementName, you actually need to run something like //ns:ElementName. However xml in ADF has no way (that I can see to pass in a namespace) so we need to be a little bit crafty in how we use XPath to query the document and instead of using a nice //ElementName we need to use an XPath function to find the element we need `  Yes I'd need the second and the third values as well but I thought I could specificy the index as I already did in the xpather tool i.e: [1]

Comment: So the question is actually *how to transform `.//Address[normalize-space(AddressTypeCode)="PICKUP"]/AddressLines/Value` into ignoring name-spaces XPath*?

Comment: if by ignoring name-spaces XPath is something that I could use in ADF then yes

Comment: I don't know about specifics of ADF, try `//*[name()="Address" and normalize-space(./*[name()="AddressTypeCode"])="PICKUP"]/*[name()="AddressLines"]/*[name()="Value"][1]`